# What is the best way to slice sequential time series pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time series pandas dataframe of ~ 100k rows with associated tasks, that has to be sequentially analysed. what is the best way to extract the index of each consecutive task . Have attached a sample format of the data below.
Intended series of tasks with their index numbers(start,end) : relax(1,2)->pause(3,4)->relax(5)->grip(6,8)->pause(9,10)->pinch(11,12)

slicing data based on task filter gives a very distorted output
which is not intended which is somewhat like this
relax->pause->grip->pinch

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need created helper column for unique consecutive `task`s and then filter by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['g'] = df['task'].ne(df['task'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df[~df.duplicated(['task','g']) | ~df.duplicated(['task','g'], keep='last')]
print (df)
                           Timestamp   task loc  age  g
1   2017-11-10 03:41:22.003809+00:00  relax  NY   32  1
2   2017-11-10 03:41:22.004809+00:00  relax  HI   26  1
3   2017-11-10 03:41:22.005809+00:00  pause  FL   25  2
4   2017-11-10 03:41:22.006809+00:00  pause  NY   32  2
5   2017-11-10 03:41:22.007809+00:00  relax  HI   26  3
6   2017-11-10 03:41:22.008809+00:00   grip  FL   25  4
8   2017-11-10 03:41:22.010809+00:00   grip  HI   26  4
9   2017-11-10 03:41:22.011809+00:00  pause  FL   25  5
10  2017-11-10 03:41:22.012809+00:00  pause  NY   32  5
11  2017-11-10 03:41:22.013809+00:00  pinch  HI   26  6
12  2017-11-10 03:41:22.014809+00:00  pinch  FL   25  6
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the suggestion. Solved my problem. Some explanation to the code steps above is appreciated .

Comment: You are welcome! If possible, you can also upvote my solution, thanks.